# C# SharpPcap send Tcp Packet

Tags: c#, tcp, ethernet, sharppcap, packetdotnet

Im trying to send a Tcp Packet over SharpPcap to an Server but it dosent work, can someone help me or explain me how i can send TcpPackets with SharpPcap and Packet.Net.

More Info's:
Im sniffing a connection and trying to send a message to the server if a specific packet incomes.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: May we see the code you've written and have a more detailed description of the problem(s) you've encountered?

Comment: my code was Device.SendPacket(byteArray); But as i see thats just sending a Packet to nowhere?

Comment: Perhaps your question could be improved with some of the tips at ["Writing the perfect question"](https://web.archive.org/web/20140709094611/http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). The code that you've provided in a comment lacks the context needed to be enlightening, e.g. declarations and initialization. Such code ought to be added to the original question via editing rather than hidden in a comment.